# In Selenium Java, how can I pass previously executed non-test method name as a parameter to a custom method?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Java in Selenium. I have declared a method `handleErrorLogs` to format error messages by passing current executed failed method name with some other parameters.
Below test method has a switch case which invokes other non-test methods. If there is a method failure, `handleErrorLogs` should be executed. How do I change following code to pass parameters to `handleErrorLogs` method by each invoking non-test methods inside the test method.

```
@Test(priority = 150, dataProvider = "getTestData")
public void AddFolderTest(String testCaseID, String testCaseName, String testCaseScope, String isExecutableFlag, String preconditionFlag, String userNameForTest, String passwordForTest, String actions, String expectedData, String inputData,String successToastMessages,String inputData2,String expectedData2,String inputData3,String inputData4,String inputData5,String expectedData3){
    try {
        test = extent.createTest(testCaseName);
        testMethodName = "AddFolder_Test"+testCaseID;
        testCaseIDForInternalUse = testCaseID;
        if(isProceed) {
            if (preconditionFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                addPrerequisites(prereqesitesData, testCaseID);
            }
            handleLogin(userNameForTest, passwordForTest);
            waitForAngular();
            navigationPanel.clickReportsTab();
            waitForAngular();
            String[] actionList = getCommaSeperateValuesAsArray(actions);
            for (String singleAction : actionList) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Action :- " + singleAction);
                logger.info("Action is :- " + singleAction);
                String methodNameExecution = "";
                    switch (singleAction) {
                        case "clickAddFolderButton":
                            addFolder.clickAddFolder();
                            break;
                        case "clickButtonActivate":
                            addFolder.clickButtonActivate();
                            break;
                        case "clickDeactivate":
                            addFolder.clickDeactivate();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }else {
                currentMethodName = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
            }
           System.out.println("************************************************************************************************");
            softAssertions.assertAll();
        }catch (Exception e){
            exceptionAssertFail(e);
            currentMethodName = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
            handleErrorLogs(e,currentMethodName,testClzname,testCaseIDForInternalUse);
            softAssertions.assertAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this.

- We first create a marker annotation that will call out a particular parameter as a test case.

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({PARAMETER})
public @interface TestCase {}
```

- We now build a TestNG listener that listens for failures on tests, and if there was a failure and if it was a data driven test, it prints out the basic information that your sample is trying to extract out.

```java
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import java.util.Optional;

public class SampleListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        Class<?> clazz = result.getTestClass().getRealClass();
        System.err.println("Class : " + clazz.getName());
        System.err.println("Method : " + methodName);
        extractTestCase(result).ifPresent(tcId -> System.err.println("Test case : " + tcId));
    }

    private static Optional<String> extractTestCase(ITestResult result) {
        ITestNGMethod itm = result.getMethod();
        if (!itm.isDataDriven()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
        Parameter[] methodParams = method.getParameters();
        int position = 0;
        for (Parameter parameter : methodParams) {
            if (parameter.isAnnotationPresent(TestCase.class)) {
                break;
            } else {
                position += 1;
            }
        }
        if (position >= methodParams.length) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();
        return Optional.of(parameters[position].toString());
    }
}
```

Here's a sample test case

```java
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(SampleListener.class)
public class ExampleTestCase {

    @Test(dataProvider = "testdata")
    public void AddFolderTest(int parameter1, @TestCase String parameter2, boolean parameter3, float parameter4) {
        if (parameter3) {
            //We are simulating a failure for demo purposes
            throw new RuntimeException("Simulating a failure");
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "testdata")
    public Object[][] getTestData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1, "one", true, 1.0f},
                {2, "two", false, 2.0f}
        };
    }
}
```

This should solve your ask.

To learn more about how to work with TestNG listeners refer to the official documentation at https://testng.org/#_specifying_listeners_with_testng_xml_or_in_java